# How to add add query parameters without using @angular/router

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to add query parameters to URL.

```
http://example.com/#/xyz?queryParams1=data&queryParams2=data
```

But don't want to navigate from one page to another. I go through angular docs but not able to get how to use it without using `@angular/router` . The idea behind it is just to track things via URL and not to navigate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can read it with plain javascript, but why would you do that if all the reading and parsing logic is there for you in the `@angular/router` package

Comment: You want to read it using Angular way, but refuse to use Angular module designed for that particular purpose. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Location from @angular/common](https://angular.io/api/common/Location)

This will allow you do update the URL without navigating, for example:

```
let queryString = 'queryParams1=data&queryParams2=data';
this.location.replaceState('/xyz', queryString);
```